# Horizontal bargraph pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I'd like to make two graphs using TiKz pgfplots or otherwise using this table below. But get the error

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `Bloodstream
>   Infection (B SI' has not been defined with 'symbolic y
>   coords={Bloodstream Infection (BSI),S urgical site infections
>   (SSI),Ventilator-associated pneumonia (VAP),Urinary tra ct infection
>   (UTI),Others}... Maybe it has been misspelled?.

Have I not correctly defined the names in `y coords`?

```
**Type of infection Mean cost   Stdev   St dev Min  Stdev Max   %**
Bloodstream Infection (BSI) 36441   37078   2883    207256  14
Surgical site infections (SSI)  25546   39875   1783    134602  17
Ventilator-associated pneumonia (VAP)   9969    2920    7904    12034   14
Urinary tract infection (UTI)   1006    503 650 1361    33
Others  1000    1000    800 5000    22
```

[image: Type of infection vs Cost]
[image: Type of infection vs %]

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
xbar, xmin=0,
xlabel={Percentage \%},
symbolic y coords={{Bloodstream Infection (BSI)},{Surgical site infections (SSI)},{Ventilator-associated pneumonia (VAP)},{Urinary tract infection (UTI)},{Others}},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
ytick=data,
]
\addplot coordinates {(14,{Bloodstream Infection (BSI)}) (17,{Surgical site infections (SSI)}) (14,{Ventilator-associated pneumonia (VAP)}) (33,{Urinary tract infection (UTI)})(22, {Others})};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} %width=6cm,height=7.59cm

\end{document}
```

Comment: same problem. The closing parenthesis of `(BSI` fools `pgfplots` that coordinate is finished. Braces around them are needed

Comment: Ahh thank you! I'm having a lot of trouble with braces today! What would the commands be to get the same colours do you know?

Comment: Updated code but continues to have problems

Comment: Remove the space in `(22, {Others})`. You only need braces if you want to protect spaces, commas etc. For single word you don't need them. Instead of this you can use numbers and then change the y tick labels.

Comment: I understand, thank you. The first graph looks like it will take me all evening.

Answer (score 9):

When symbolic coordinates are used, the pattern given by `symbolic <x or y> coords` should match exactly the pattern given in the coordinates. Hence the whitespace before `{Others}` should be removed.

Moreover, if there are characters such as parentheses or commas in the symbolic coordinate itself that would cause confusion during coordinate parsing of `(<some text with ( or comma> , <some text with ( or comma>)` they should be put withing brace pairs such that the parser will take them as a group of chars instead of finding a comma and start parsing the next coordinate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
xbar, xmin=0,
xlabel={Percentage \%},
symbolic y coords={%
    {Bloodstream Infection (BSI)},
    {Surgical site infections (SSI)},
    {Ventilator-associated pneumonia (VAP)},
    {Urinary tract infection (UTI)},
    Others},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={horizontal},
ytick=data,
]
\addplot coordinates {
    (14,{Bloodstream Infection (BSI)}) 
    (17,{Surgical site infections (SSI)}) 
    (14,{Ventilator-associated pneumonia (VAP)}) 
    (33,{Urinary tract infection (UTI)})
    (22,Others)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} %width=6cm,height=7.59cm
\end{document}
```

[image]